# Windows + Cygwin + Single Line If Else + Puppet

Tags: windows, git, bash, cygwin, puppet

So I have a single line bash command that checks if a directory exists. If it does, it git pulls, if it doesn't, it clones the repository. I am running a Cygwin on my Windows box and when I run this command in Cygwin it works perfectly:

```
if [ -d C:/repo ]; then cd C:/repo && "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe" pull; else "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe" clone -b develop https://repo.git C:/repo; fi
```

When I run the same command from Puppet though like  this:

```
exec {'checkout repository':
    command => "if [ -d C:/repo ]; then cd C:/repo && "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe" pull; else "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe" clone -b develop https://repo.git C:/repo; fi"
}
```

I get error:

> Error: ' if [ -d C:/repo ]; then cd C:/repo && "C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe" pull; else "C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe" clone -b develop https://repo.git C:/repo; fi'
>   is not qualified and no path was specified. Please qualify the command
>   or specify a path.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Could it be your quotes? Try wrapping the entire command in ' instead of " and leaving the executable paths wrapped in ".

Comment: I tried that, the same error.

Comment: Found this as I'm sure you have: https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-sudo/issues/10 the issue seems to come from incorrect file paths, if you're running this on the same machine there shouldn't be an issue. However perhaps puppet does some funky stuff when it comes to window style paths?

Comment: Have you tried to move git.exe to a folder where the path doesn't contain spaces?

Comment: I have no concrete reason to believe this would change anything, but I can't help but fixate on the Windows-style paths and wonder when I see them. Could you try changing them to the Unix-style "/cygdrive/c/..." just to see if it makes any difference? You can use the `cygpath` command to convert the paths if you don't want to do it manually.

Comment: Just a thought -- should this command be running under Bash on Puppet?

Comment: Try `command => "bash -c 'if [ -d .... '"`.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet is a native Windows program (it works without cygwin). What you have written in the command -parameter is basically a short sh(1) script. Windows does not have sh(1) by default, although it is provided by cygwin. So puppet on windows will not try to execute the contents of command via sh(1). It should be the (absolute) name of a windows executable, with optional parameters. If you wish to invoke a cmd.exe builtin, you need to do something like `command => 'cmd /c dir'`.

Answer (score 0):

escape your quotes or use single quotes and use cygdrive, so your code should look like this:

```
exec {'checkout repository':
    command => "if [ -d C:/repo ]; then cd C:/repo && 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe' pull; else 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe' clone -b develop https://repo.git C:/repo; fi"
}
```

and this:

```
exec {'checkout repository':
    command => "if [ -d /cygdrive/c/repo ]; then cd /cygdrive/c/repo && '/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe' pull; else '/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe' clone -b develop https://repo.git /cygdrive/c/repo; fi"
}
```

And if you even install git inside cygwin, you can make it simpler:

```
exec {'checkout repository':
    command => "if [ -d /cygdrive/c/repo ]; then cd /cygdrive/c/repo && git pull; else git clone -b develop https://repo.git /cygdrive/c/repo; fi"
}
```